MissingCodeError: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response
I'm trying to post a thread (as in Meta's Threads.net) using the API. I'm exploring this python wrapper https://github.com/marclove/pythreads but I can't get through the authentification process.
Here is what I'm doing:
THREADS_REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth"
THREADS_APP_ID = "" #my app id
THREADS_API_SECRET = "" #my app secret

import os

os.environ['THREADS_SSL_CERT_FILEPATH'] = "threads-sample.meta.pem"
os.environ['THREADS_SSL_KEY_FILEPATH'] = "threads-sample.meta-key.pem"

from pythreads import threads

os.environ['THREADS_REDIRECT_URI'] = THREADS_REDIRECT_URI
os.environ['THREADS_APP_ID'] = THREADS_APP_ID
os.environ['THREADS_API_SECRET'] = THREADS_API_SECRET

auth_url, state_key = threads.Threads.authorization_url()

requested_url = auth_url  # I'm not sure this is what I should be doing...

credentials = Threads.complete_authorization(requested_url, state_key)

And here is the error I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[115], line 1
    credentials = threads.Threads.complete_authorization(requested_url, state_key)

  File ~\Anaconda3\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythreads\threads.py:212 in complete_authorization
    Threads.fetch_user_id_and_token(

  File ~\Anaconda3\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythreads\threads.py:273 in fetch_user_id_and_token
    response = session.fetch_token(

  File ~\Anaconda3\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py:271 in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_uri_response(

  File ~\Anaconda3\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\web_application.py:220 in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)

  File ~\Anaconda3\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py:284 in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise MissingCodeError("Missing code parameter in response.")

MissingCodeError: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.

I don't understand this error message.

Gnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
